# Transform a changelog in a daily changelog with an incremental model

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I would like to make an incremental DBT model of a daily changelog from a changelog that looks like the following:

```
    ID  TIMESTAMP        DATA     OPERATION
    id1 2023-01-01 13:40 data1_v1 create
    id1 2023-01-01 15:00 data1_v2 update
    id1 2023-01-03 00:02 data1_v3 update
    id1 2023-01-04 05:04 data1_v3 delete
    id2 2023-01-01 XX:XX data2_v1 create
    id2 2023-01-02 XX:XX data2_v2 update
    id2 2023-01-04 XX:XX data2_v3 update
```

I would like to accomplish a daily picture of the data of each id (filtering deletes each day), so we get a daily changelog:

```
    ID  DATE       DATA    
    id1 2023-01-01 data1_v2
    id1 2023-01-02 data1_v2
    id1 2023-01-03 data1_v3
    id2 2023-01-01 data2_v1
    id2 2023-01-02 data2_v2
    id2 2023-01-03 data2_v2
    id2 2023-01-04 data2_v3
```

Mentioning:

- For id1 in date 2023-01-01, data1_v2 is the data we want because it
  is the latest that day
- id1 does not figure in 2023-01-04 because it
  was deleted
- id2 in date 2023-01-03 is data2_v2 since the it didn't
  change that day

We use BigQuery as our warehouse connected to DBT.

My current approach is the following:

```sql
with
    days as (
        select day
        from unnest(generate_date_array(date_sub(current_date(), interval 6 month), current_date())) day
    ),
    changelog as (
        select date, timestamp, document_id, data
        from {{ ref("base_firestore_export__event_raw_changelog") }}
    ),
    daily_changelog as (
        select
            date,
            document_id,
            last_value(data ignore nulls) over (order by timestamp) as data
        from days d
        left join changelog c on d.day = c.date
        {% if is_incremental() %}
            -- this filter will only be applied on an incremental run
            where date > (select max(date) from {{ this }}) 
        {% endif %}
    )
select *
from daily_changelog
```

but I get a memory error:

```
Database Error in rpc request (from remote system) Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 122% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thansks!

Comment: How big is `base_firestore_export__event_raw_changelog `? And do you need the whole table to start with? I'd try filtering it a bit, and see if the `allotted memory` error persists

Comment: Thanks for answering @AleixCC The table is 89.56 logical GB. I only need a photo of each document for each day of the last 6 months, but in order to get that, I think I need the whole table. Imagine a case where a document last changed 7 months ago, then if I filter out records before 6 months ago, that document would not appear in my result. Am I right?

Comment: Are you using DBT, but not using an incremental model to process your `daily` events? It sounds like you are trying to create a daily Fact table that spans ~2d (today and yesterday) to update today's state